# how to add click function to a text box of a particular for

Tags: jquery

I need to add a click function to a textbox with ID "test"  which is in form with name "reason"

I need to to add this because there are multiple  textbox with id "test" in the same page .

thanks

Comment: You should have only one element with a specific `id`.

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this but first change the ID to class. ID is unique and only one element should have it. Where as class can be across multiple objects.

```
$("form[name=reason] textarea.test").click(function(){
    //What the function does
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids are supposed to be unique, just give it a unique id and select it.

```
$('#yourinput').click(function(){...
```